# Setting the background colour back to original after jquery changes it

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

Basically I have a table with many rows. The Table alternates between white and grey backgrounds using some css

```
.profile tr:nth-child(odd)    { background:#eee; }
.profile tr:nth-child(even)    { background:none; }
```

Now I want the user to be able to select a row and it highlights into yellow. Done with some simple Jquery

```
    $(".Select").click(function() {
        //Deselect all other Rows
        $(".Select").show().prev().hide().parent().parent().css('background', 'none');



        //get Id
        var Row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var MatchId = Row.attr('id');
        $(this).hide().prev().show();
        Row.css('background', '#FFFFBA');
    });
```

Problem is where i grab all rows with the $(".select").......parent().parent().css('background....

setting it to "none" makes all the rows white and loses the alternative colouring is there a way to return the background property to its original state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**create a third class:**

```
.profile tr.hover    { background:#FFFFBA; }
```

instead of

```
 Row.css('background', '#FFFFBA');
```

you do

```
  Row.addClass("hover");
```

and instead of

```
  $(".Select").s.//.parent().css('background', 'none');
```

you do

```
  $(".Select").s.//.parent().removeClass("hover");
```

the // is just to shorten the long line.

Comment: why not just use the :hover property in the CSS where you set `.profile tr:hover {background:#FFFFBA;}` since that requires no javascript?

Comment: @drachenstein I share your concern on: "However, I'm not entirely sure from your code that that's what you're wanting to do", I kept it jQuery wise.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I cant do hover as its about selecting a row not hovering a row! so I want a row highlighted until its done changed to another row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all that trouble, just use the CSS selector for the TR in your .css stylesheet and use the `:hover` markup and let the browser handle it. Any job you can offload to the underlying browser you should.

However, I'm not entirely sure from your code that that's what you're wanting to do. It looks like you want to change the background of some other row than the one you're on. If that's the case then you'll need to attach a bit of `.data()` to the target object and use a mouse out event to change it back from whatever you stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".Select").show().prev().hide().parent().parent().css('background', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Caspar is correct here, for a few reasons:

1. You keep your presentation in the CSS
2. Browsers apply CSS faster than manipulating the style object in JavaScript
3. If you add additional styles to the highlighted item (such as a border, bold text, etc.) there's no performance hit (see reason 2).

Having said that, if you want to just keep the code you have, simply remove the odd rows from your jQuery selector using the `$.not()` selector:

```
$(".Select").show().prev().hide().parent().parent().not(':nth-child(odd)').css('background', 'none');
```